# aggregate mongodb result agroup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Someone with me I'm a light, I'm not welcome.

I do not know if I would have to do this adjustment with a group

```
db.users.aggregate([
        { $match : {  '_id': ObjectId('5956a6361b9f673dc629c9a6') } },
        { '$unwind': { 'path': '$profile', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } },
        {$lookup: {
                'from': 'institution',
                'localField': 'profile.departament',
                'foreignField': 'departament._id',
                'as': 'Institution'
            }   
        },
        { '$unwind': { 'path': '$Institution', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } },

        {$project: {
          'Profile':{
                'name' : '$name',
                'photo': '$photo',
                'nickname' : '$nickname',
                'institution' : {name: '$Institution.name', photo: '$Institution.photo'},        
                'departments' : {title : '$Institution.departament.title', category: '$Institution.departament.category'} ,
             }
           }
        },

        { $group : {
              '_id' : '$_id', 
              'profile': { $push : '$Profile' },

            }
        },




    ])
```

I can not do the group 'institution' o result it is like this

```
"departments" : {
            "title" : [
                "Terror by africa", 
                "Africa"
            ], 
            "category" : [
                "Sub-15", 
                "Sub-20"
            ]
        }
```

As I'm trying to let not have to use array position

```
"departments" : {
            "title" : [{
                name: "Terror by africa", 
                category: "Sub-15", 
            },{
                name: "Africa", 
                category: "Sub-20", 
            }], 

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `$group` stage and update `departments` projection to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to transform the keys.

Something like

```
{
    departments: {
        $map: {
            input: "$Institution.departament",
            as: "departament",
            in: {
                name: '$$departament.title',
                category: '$$departament.category'
            }
        }
    }
 }
```